# How to save image in BLOB form using Ajax and passing data in model

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I want to know how to save image in BLOB (Binary Large Object) form using Ajax and passing data in model including image.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow? plz follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: We are passing as array using Ajax and get data into model except image array.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. for saving time convert to base64 and save it. 
   2 for editing time convert base64 to image.
   i done this process i got output

Comment: I have to save Image not text . Time is in textual format but image in form of Byte array . Is this method works for Byte ?